# Поиск утечек памяти в node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

С помощью каких средств, можно обнаружить и найти место, где происходит 
 утечка памяти в javascript? 
Интересует как node js так и клиентский javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Стандартный [инспектор](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/cli.html#cli_inspect_host_port) в ноде может помочь. Нужно запустить ноду с флагом --inspect и ссылку, которая выведется в консоли открыть в браузере. Откроется хромовский девтулс. Для поиска утечек есть такой метод сравнения. Сначала вы делаете дамп памяти в момент старта приложения или через непродолжительное время работы. Потом дамп делается через некоторое время работы приложения. Далее вы сравниваете эти два дампа и ищете объекты, которых больше всего. Это и есть ваша утечка.

По своему опыту могу сказать, что утечки памяти это результат неверной / неудачной архитектуры. Попробуйте использовать typescript, например.

В добавок, утечки бывает сложно найти. Бывают как быстрые, так и медленные утечки. Медленные это когда память в течение долгого времени по чуть чуть утекает. У меня лично бывали только медленные. Решалась это проблема простым перезапуском. Спасибо докеру, что может перезапустить контейнер при привышении памяти.